# php load data into fancybox when is load with JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, fancybox

I have a php page with a fancybox.
I have a a page in php that with jquery shown a fancybox.
When the fancybox is shown I need to load data from database.
Code of the click event:

```
$("a#addActivitat").click(function(){
            var retorn;
            $.getJSON('aplicacio/agendaLoadData.php?action=loadIdAct',function(data){
                retorn = data;
            });
            alert(retorn);  
        });
```

The alert is undefined

the code of fancybox:

```
<div id="agendaAddAct">
        <form method="post" action="" target="workFrame" id="actionform">
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="idRel" id="idRel"/>
            </p>
            <input type="button" value="Afegir activitat" class="btnsubmit" id="afegirActivitat"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I need that the value returned of php call is loaded in the idRel input.
And the code of the agendaLoadData that is called with JSON:

```
$var = new facanabbdd();
echo json_encode($var->getMaxValueRel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:

code of php page:

```
$("a#addActivitat").click(function(){
            $.getJSON('aplicacio/agendaLoadData.php?action=loadIdAct',
                       function(data){
                $('#idRel').val(data);
            });     
        });
```

And code of agendaLoadData

```
echo json_decode("43");
```

The error was that I call the function json_encode and I need to call the function json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `$.getJSON` correctly. Keep in mind that Ajax requests are asynchronous (Ajax does after all mean Asynchronous JavaScript and XML).
Therefore your `retorn` variable will not be filled with the value obtained from the Ajax call.

What you should do instead is update your DOM when you receive the data (ie. in your callback function)

```
$("a#addActivitat").click(function(){
    $.getJSON('aplicacio/agendaLoadData.php?action=loadIdAct', function(data){
        $('#idRel').val(data.value);
    });
});
```

Provided your returned JSON document is like

```
{
    "value": 42
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your alert inside the success handler, it will alert the data, if data is returned from your server. Try it like this:

```
$("a#addActivitat").click(function(){
    $.getJSON('aplicacio/agendaLoadData.php?action=loadIdAct',function(data){
         $("#idRel").val(data);
         var retorn = $.parseJSON( data );
         alert(retorn);
    });
});
```

Comment: That probably means there is no data returned, could be the adress is wrong, or that the returned data is not valid json. Hard to tell really ?